# Windows Store App - XAML C# - How to access Page.Resource in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a static resource in my Page1.xaml.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="PageName">Page 1</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
```

I want to access this resource in the code, but can't see how to do it. I'm sure I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

My `MainPage` uses a single `Frame` for navigation and the `MainPage` has the title of the page that is displayed in the `Frame`.

I would have thought I could do something like this in my `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
    string title = "NOT SET!";
    rootFrame.Resources.TryGetValue("PageName", out title);
    pageTitle.Text = title;
```

Where `rootFrame` is the frame that is displaying the `Page1`.

However this doesn't compile as `TryGetValue` takes an `object` as its first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did in the end.

```
        object title = "NOT SET!";
        object key = "PageName";
        var page = (Page)rootFrame.Content;
        page.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out title);
```

Comment: valid for UWP also

Comment: this.Resources.TryGetValue("[resource_Key]", out object o);